# What are the specifications on the RAM inside my computer?

Tags: memory

I have a Dell Dimension 9200 that I bought 4 years ago. I want to find out the exact specifications (manufacturer, speed, timings, etc.). Is there a way to get this specific info without having to open up the PC (it's buried in and under a bunch of furniture, I'd perfer not to have to dig it out).

All I know about it right now is that it is 4 1GB sticks of DDR2 RAM at 667 Mhz. It is the standard RAM that shipped with the computer 4 years ago (from Dell). Does anyone know what the specifications are of the RAM that Dell used in this particular model of computer 4 years ago?

Note: I've done my research before coming here. CPU-Z, EVEREST, and AIDA32 all have been unable to give me any more information other than 4 x 1GB @ 667Mhz. I can't find any specifications in the Dell online manuals either (at least not as specific as I want).

Thanks

-Faken

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like System Information for Windows should give you the information you need. Their memory screenshot page looks like it has all the timing, manufacturer, etc. information
http://www.gtopala.com/siw-hardware/memory.html

SIW is available as a free portable or installable download, down at the bottom of http://www.gtopala.com/siw-download.html

Comment: Definitely an awesome tool! I would highly recommend it.

Comment: Very nice, thank you very much! It displays all the exact specifications of the RAM. A side question, if the memory summery section says that i have single bit ECC, is that that my motherboard supports ECC or that my RAM has it on?

Answer (score 1):

Find the Service Tag, go to Dell support and click on Drivers & Download, click on the option to "Choose by Service Tag", enter your service tag (printed on a label on your Dell). On the drivers page that opens, on the left hand side under Product Support there is a link to go to System Configuration. This will give you a list of what type's fitted.

**OR**

If you're not happy with the info there then another option is to go to Kingston Memory or Crucial Memory website and enter the make/model in their memory selector list.

[Computer memory upgrades for Dell Dimension 9200 Desktop/PC from Crucial.com](http://www.crucial.com/uk/store/listparts.aspx?model=Dimension%209200)

[Search Results for: Dell Dimension 9200 / 9200C](http://www.ec.kingston.com/ecom/configurator_new/modelsinfo.asp?SysID=31916&mfr=Dell&model=Dimension+9200+%2F+9200C&search_type=&root=us&LinkBack=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.kingston.com&Sys=31916-Dell-Dimension+9200+%2F+9200C&distributor=0&submit1=Search)

Comment: +1.  I've had good luck with Dell support providing good hardware information on machines with unknown configurations.

Comment: I'm assuming you mean URL shortening services. You could still html-ize your links by using the Hyperlink button or do `[Example](http://example.com)`. People can see the links by hovering over them or tabbing to them.